# C# Lambda expression query parameter reads as null with IQueryable, but works with List?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having some difficulty understanding why my application is behaving the way it is.  This is a MVC in .Net Core.  I have very similar code in two different areas.  One area returns results based on a given user, and in the other, the results are based on a search string.  This first section is for the results based on the user and works as I want it to.

```
    [NonAction]
    private IQueryable<Film> GetUserFilms(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        // Returns all Films of the user that the current User is authorized to see.  Audio, Media, and User of the film is included.
        return _context.Films
            .Include(f => f.Audio)
            .Include(f => f.Media)
            .Include(f => f.User)
            .Where(f => (f.UserID == user.Id) && (!f.IsPrivate || User.IsInRole("Admin") || f.UserID == _userManager.GetUserId(User)));
    }

    [NonAction]
    private List<Film> GetUserFilmsByGenre(ApplicationUser user, string genre = null)
    {
        // Returns all Films of the user for a specific genre, displaying only those that the current User is authorized to see 
        return GetUserFilms(user).Include(f => f.FilmGenres).Where(f => f.FilmGenres.Any(fg => fg.Genre.Name == genre)).ToList();
    }

    [NonAction]
    private List<Film> GetUserFilmsByMediaFormat(ApplicationUser user, string mediaFormat = null)
    {
        // Returns all Films of the user for a specific MediaFormat, displaying only those that the current User is authorized to see 

        return GetUserFilms(user).Where(f => f.Media.Name == mediaFormat).ToList();
    }
```

This next section is the area that is based on the search string.

```
[NonAction]
    private IQueryable<Film> GetFilmsByTitle(string title)
    {
        // Returns all Films, containing search parameter, that the current User is authorized to see.  
        // Audio, Media, FilmGenre.Genre and User of the film are included.
        return _context.Films
            .Include(f => f.Audio)
            .Include(f => f.Media)
            .Include(f => f.User)
            .Where(f => f.Name.ToLower().Contains(title.ToLower())
            && ((!f.IsPrivate && !f.User.IsPrivate) || User.IsInRole("Admin") || f.UserID == _userManager.GetUserId(User)));
        }

    [NonAction]
    private List<Film> GetAllFilmsByGenre(string title, string genre = null)
    {
        // Returns all Films, containing the search parameter, for a specific genre, 
        // displaying only those that the current User is authorized to see 
        return GetFilmsByTitle(title).Where(f => f.FilmGenres.Any(fg => fg.Genre.Name == genre)).ToList();
    }

    [NonAction]
    private List<Film> GetAllFilmsByMediaFormat(string title, string mediaFormat = null)
    {
        // Returns all Films, containing the search parameter, for a specific MediaFormat, 
        // displaying only those that the current User is authorized to see 
        return GetFilmsByTitle(title).Where(f=> f.Media.Name == mediaFormat).ToList();
    }
```

Now when the GetAllFilmsByMediaFormat method is ran, I get a nullReferenceException.  Through some testing, I've determined that the f.Media within the .Where is reading as null for some reason.  If I break up the return and just have GetFilmsByTitle(title) first, I can verify that the Media property has a valid value for every item in the results.  I am not understanding why then that the lambda expression sees it as being null.

Additionally, I get a nullReferenceException on the GetAllFilmsByGenre method as the fg.Genre is reading as null.

Now, I have changed things to what it is below, changing the IQueryable into a List, and putting an Include for FilmGenre and a ThenInclude for Genre into my GetFilmsByTitle method.  This performs as I expect, and similar to how the other code works in the other section.

I am just trying to figure out why this is the case?  Why is IQueryable acceptable in one instance, but not the other?  Why is it coming up as null in the lambda expression when there is a value immediately before that exectution?  Why do I need the extra .ThenInclude for one query and not the other?

Here is the working code:

```
    [NonAction]
    private List<Film> GetFilmsByTitle(string title)
    {
        // Returns all Films, containing search parameter, that the current User is authorized to see.  
        // Audio, Media, FilmGenre.Genre and User of the film are included.
        IQueryable<Film> films = _context.Films
            .Include(f => f.Audio)
            .Include(f => f.Media)
            .Include(f => f.User)
            .Include(f=> f.FilmGenres)
                .ThenInclude(fg=>fg.Genre)
            .Where(f => f.Name.ToLower().Contains(title.ToLower())
            && ((!f.IsPrivate && !f.User.IsPrivate) || User.IsInRole("Admin") || f.UserID == _userManager.GetUserId(User)));
        return films.ToList();
    }

    [NonAction]
    private List<Film> GetAllFilmsByGenre(string title, string genre = null)
    {
        // Returns all Films, containing the search parameter, for a specific genre, 
        // displaying only those that the current User is authorized to see 
        return GetFilmsByTitle(title).Where(f => f.FilmGenres.Any(fg => fg.Genre.Name == genre)).ToList();
    }

    [NonAction]
    private List<Film> GetAllFilmsByMediaFormat(string title, string mediaFormat = null)
    {
        // Returns all Films, containing the search parameter, for a specific MediaFormat, 
        // displaying only those that the current User is authorized to see 
        return GetFilmsByTitle(title).Where(f=> f.Media.Name == mediaFormat).ToList();
```